# PrimeNG grid not being displayed on a page, and not getting any errors either

Tags: angular, webpack, primeng

I have an Angularjs 2 project using .Net core. I am trying out PrimeNG datatable for doing CRUD operation. I am calling an API service to get data from database. I have written 2 components one which is looping through the data from service using simple  and I am getting records on the page.
Second page uses PrimeNg datatable and uses same service, but nothing gets displayed on the screen. When trying to debug the code using F12 I do not see any errors, the call to service is returning proper data. But in the dom object I do not see any data being generated. 
Attached is code for HTML and ts files

## Project Details

```
<p-dataTable [value]="projects" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedProject" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" [paginator]="true" rows="3" [responsive]="true">
    <header>CRUD for Projects</header>
    <p-column field="id" header="Id" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="projectcode" header="Code" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="projectname" header="Description" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="fkclient" header="Client Id" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="clientcode" header="Client Code" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

TS File

```
import {OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {DataTableModule, SharedModule, DataTable, Column} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Header} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Footer} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {ProjectDetails} from './ProjectDetails';

@Component({
    selector: 'fetch-data', 
    template: require('./fetchdata.component.html')
})
export class FetchDataComponent implements OnInit {

    newProject: boolean;

    public projects: ProjectDetails[];

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:53447/api/project/').subscribe(result => {
            this.projects = result.json();
        });
    }
}
```

ProjectDetails domain model

```
export interface ProjectDetails {
    id: number;
    projectcode: string;
    projectname: string;
    fkclient: number;
    clientcode: string;
}
```

What I suspect is that for some reason the webpack is not including PrimeNG related files into my dist folder. I had to actually copy the CSS files also manually but I was not sure what other files need to go.

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported DatatableModule into your AppModule?

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        DatatableModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
   ],
   bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hi I had the import in the module where I was using the datatable, but I also added the import into AppModule as mentioned above. Now I get another error.

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: ReferenceError: Event is not defined
at C:\Vishal\CBIAWeb\node_modules\primeng\components\button\button.js:119:42
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Vishal\CBIAWeb\node_modules\primeng\components\button\button.js:174:2)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: It clearly says that you have problem with some button on your page. It is not represented on your original issue, so cannot help you with that for now. Check all your source code for proper using "Event" or "event" variable... Also make sure you imported primeng module everywhere